# GridView adds quote marks when updating data using DevExpressEditorBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

When I select the Edit link and then Update the record .
However, the string fields in the object are being returned with quotation marks around them.
I am using DevExpressEditorBinder.

```
public ActionResult GridViewPartialUpdate([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] DevExpressMvc.Models.Employee item)
{
    var model = db.Employees;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var modelItem = model.FirstOrDefault(it => it.id == item.id);
            if (modelItem != null)
            {
                this.UpdateModel(modelItem);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.EditError = e.Message;
        }
    }
    else
        ViewBag.EditError = "Please, correct all errors.";
    return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", model.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to Global.acax helped it

```
 protected void Application_Start()

 {
     ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new   DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DevExpressEditorsBinder();
 }
```